# encrypting a password value in gsp

Tags: grails, encryption, passwords, gsp

In my HTML form I have a password field which I want to encyrpt before I send it in the URL form post.

so I call a js function on submit click like validateAndEncrypt() which basically I want to use to encrypt the password.

How can I encrypt this password value?

1) I have a inbuilt codec class (DESCodec) with methods encrypt and decrypt, can I use this codec in gsp directly? - if yes how do I feed the password value to DESCodec from javascript.
2) Is there a method using plain javascript to encrypt the password value?

Which method is should I go for?

Thanks
Priyank

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: use SSL.

Long answer: private key encryption algorithms like DES are not practical to use on the web because the browser needs to share a private key with the server.  In order to transmit it securely, you need to use some form of public key exchange.  After you've implemented that, you've basically reinvented SSL, but probably buggy and insecurely.

Comment: But we have already implemented ssl over http (so that we have a  url like https://.....) and even then the params in the URL are still visible on post in Firebug. SSL is layer which sits between presentation and network as far as I know so the URLs and all will be encrypted once the requested is submitted over the network, the end user still sees the unencrypted data?

Comment: Firebug and similar tools capture the request parameters before they're encrypted by SSL.  The user will be able to see the unencrypted parameters, but this shouldn't really be cause for concern, since it's the user who enters this data.

Comment: We did a test on the current system and a user can see the id, password fields, can modify the id (by guessing the next sequential number) & password fields and could successfully change the passwords of other users in the database.

Comment: That's not an encryption bug, it's an authentication bug.  You need to verify the user who submits a password change request has the authority to make the change.

Comment: Thanks, we have removed the bug, but part of the requirement is also to encrypt the password so that its not visible in plaintext anywhere (needs to be encrypted). So figuring out an algorithm to implement this. any pointer on this might be useful..

Answer (score 1):

1. Use SSL (https)
2. It is unnecessary to use client side encryption with Javascript.  Keeping the client side encryption and the server side decryption in sync is probably more work than it is worth.
3. Seriously: Trust SSL

> can I use this codec in gsp directly?

No, you can't use server side code on the client.  You would need a client side library to encode form elements before submitting them if you choose to double encrypt your forms.

You do have javascript encryption options *if this is really what your application really requires*.

- http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/
- http://www.tero.co.uk/des/
- http://www.jcryption.org/

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I want to know if there is a library where I can encrypt using JavaScript and decrypt in the grails controller. I guess I have to write a common logic and implement it myself or does any of the libraries above or otherwise provide this feature?

Answer (score 0):

just use ssl encrypion (https)

Answer (score 0):

Using SSL may be a simpler and more effective solution - and it will encrypt any other data you might send that is sensitive.  The solution you are trying to create is exactly what SSL is designed for.